# Cobra and Viper to edit config

Tags: go, go-cobra, viper-go

I've got a basic config file that's mashalled and unmarshalled by viper to a struct.

```
type Config struct {
    field1  string
    field2  string
    field3  string
}
```

I want to set up cobra to let me do `myapp get field1` and `myapp set field1 foo` for each field in my config. Ideally without hand-coding a command for each, since they all just call `viper.Set` and write the file.. Is it possible to get Cobra to just auto-generate the sub-commands based on the struct somehow?

Comment: Why would you make a command for each field? Just make "set" and "get" the commands and make the field name/value parameters